# ScrollView moves horizontally and vertically both..Frame issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a `UITableView` on didselect i add a subview which is of the same size of `UITableView` ie it covers the `UITableView` completely,Inside the subview i have a `UITableView` and on tap of a button of one of its cell it opens another popup in the centre of subview.when i close the popup with `[self.view removefromsuperview]` the subview layout gets disturbed and the subview scrolls horizontally and vertically both.

//code which adds subview on tableview

```
  self.ffwddetail.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 
  self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
  [self addChildViewController:self.ffwddetail];
  [_ffwddetail didMoveToParentViewController:self];
  [self.view addSubview:_ffwddetail.view];
```

//code which shows popup on tap of button of tableview inside subview

```
  TYCCustomerSupportVc * popup=[[TYCCustomerSupportVc alloc]init];
    popup.fromfwd=YES;
    popup.ContactDictionary=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
      NSLog(@"contact dict is %@",[GlobalClass 
    singleton].Contactjson);
   popup.ContactDictionary= [GlobalClass singleton].Contactjson;
    popup.btntag=celltag;
    popup.view.frame=
   CGRectMake(_parentController.view.frame.origin.x+18,100 ,  
    popup.view.frame.size.width, popup.view.frame.size.height);
    [_parentController.view addSubview:popup.view];
    [_parentController addChildViewController:popup];
    [self.parentController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    //code to remove popup 
     [self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: `self.ffwddetailview.frame = self.view.bounds`

Comment: Use presentation controllers for showing popups